# IQKeyboardManager keyboard appears while popping out a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using `IQKeyboardManager` for all my textfields. On click of the back button and also on `viewDidDisappear`, I am doing:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

I also tried delaying the popup action after resigning the keyboard but still, before popping out the controller, the keyboard appears for a while (the controller has a table view inside). Please help.

Comment: Did you tried removing the library? I mean did you check that the issue still persist after removing library or it doesn't happen after removing library?

Comment: It happens because of the library only otherwise its working fine, but my app requires to use its functionalities throughout. So, I have to manage this as I don't have the option to remove it.

Comment: If you think there is an issue then you should probably open an issue in github repo issue tracker and upload a sample project there for debug.